# Oracle SQL Percent Difference Same Column

Tags: oracle12c

Given the following auction data, how would you find the percent difference between a persons most recent and previous bid for a product using Oracle SQL?

The duplicate sequence (SEQ) for person A and B is representative of data I am working with.

An example of your SQL would be very appreciated.

```
TXN_TIME              | SEQ | PERSON | PRODUCT | TRANSACTION | BID  |
2017-11-22 15:41:10:0 | 20  | A      | 1       | BID         | 12   |
2017-11-22 15:35:10:0 | 10C | A      | 1       | CXLBID      | NULL |
2017-11-22 15:34:25:0 | 10  | A      | 1       | BID         | 10   |
2017-11-22 15:35:40:0 | 6   | A      | 2       | BID         | 4    |
2017-11-22 15:34:50:0 | 1C  | A      | 2       | CXLBID      | NULL |
2017-11-22 15:34:20:0 | 1   | A      | 2       | BID         | 5    |
2017-11-22 15:35:45:0 | 6   | B      | 2       | BID         | 2    |
2017-11-22 15:34:55:0 | 1C  | B      | 2       | CXLBID      | NULL |
2017-11-22 15:34:25:0 | 1   | B      | 2       | BID         | 1    |
```

Answer (score 0):

We could try to use LEAD/LAG analytic functions if they be available.  But one approach here would be to use a CTE to identify just the most recent, and immediately prior, bid for each person, and then compare these two values.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT PERSON, BID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON ORDER BY TXN_TIME DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE TRANSACTION = 'BID'
)

SELECT
    t1.PERSON,
    100*(t1.BID - t2.BID) / t2.BID AS BID_PCT_DIFF
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.PERSON = t2.PERSON AND
       t1.rn = 1 AND t2.rn = 2;
```

[image]

This output looks correct, because person `A` went from a bid of 4 to 12, which is an increase of 8, or 200%, and person `B` went from a bid of 1 to 2, which is a 100% increase.

I created a demo below in SQL Server, because I always have difficulties getting Oracle demos to work.  But my query is just ANSI SQL and should run the same on either SQL Server or Oracle.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Good thing you are using Oracle 12. This way you can use the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause, which is perfect for your problem.

I calculate the `CHANGE` column in the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause, using the `LAST()` function with the optional second argument, which is a logical offset within the set of rows mapped to a specific pattern variable. I **format** the `CHANGE` column in the `SELECT` clause - I use a favorite hack, using the "currency" symbol to attach the percent sign... you can modify the formatting any way you want, without affecting the calculation (which is hidden in the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause).

```
with auction_data ( txn_time, seq, person, product, transaction, bid ) as (
 select timestamp '2017-11-22 15:41:10', '20' , 'A', 1, 'BID'   , 12   from dual union all
 select timestamp '2017-11-22 15:35:10', '10C', 'A', 1, 'CXLBID', NULL from dual union all
 select timestamp '2017-11-22 15:34:25', '10' , 'A', 1, 'BID'   , 10   from dual union all
 select timestamp '2017-11-22 15:35:40', '6'  , 'A', 2, 'BID'   , 4    from dual union all
 select timestamp '2017-11-22 15:34:50', '1C' , 'A', 2, 'CXLBID', NULL from dual union all
 select timestamp '2017-11-22 15:34:20', '1'  , 'A', 2, 'BID'   , 5    from dual union all
 select timestamp '2017-11-22 15:35:45', '6'  , 'B', 2, 'BID'   , 2    from dual union all
 select timestamp '2017-11-22 15:34:55', '1C' , 'B', 2, 'CXLBID', NULL from dual union all
 select timestamp '2017-11-22 15:34:25', '1'  , 'B', 2, 'BID'   , 1    from dual
)
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
select txn_time, seq, person, product, transaction, bid, 
       to_char( 100 * (change - 1), '999D0L', 'nls_currency=''%''') as change
from   auction_data
match_recognize(
  partition by person, product
  order     by txn_time
  measures  case when classifier() = 'B' then bid / last(B.bid, 1) end as change
  all rows per match
  pattern ( (B|A)* )
  define  B as B.transaction = 'BID'
);

TXN_TIME            SEQ PERSON    PRODUCT TRANSACTION        BID           CHANGE         
------------------- --- ------ ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------------
2017-11-22 15:34:25 10  A               1 BID                 10                 
2017-11-22 15:35:10 10C A               1 CXLBID                                 
2017-11-22 15:41:10 20  A               1 BID                 12            20.0%
2017-11-22 15:34:20 1   A               2 BID                  5                 
2017-11-22 15:34:50 1C  A               2 CXLBID                                 
2017-11-22 15:35:40 6   A               2 BID                  4           -20.0%
2017-11-22 15:34:25 1   B               2 BID                  1                 
2017-11-22 15:34:55 1C  B               2 CXLBID                                 
2017-11-22 15:35:45 6   B               2 BID                  2           100.0%
```